# select a different option on first load

Tags: wheelnav.js

Is it possible to have a different option selected on page load?

the default selected option always seems to be the first menu item in createWheel();

How do I default to the 3rd option?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the zero-indexed selectedNavItemIndex property before createWheel().

```
myWheelnav.selectedNavItemIndex = 2;
```